# seam-gen vs eclipse seam web project

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, seam

I'm trying to learn how to develop a j2ee web application but is currently figuring out what's the advantage of using seam-gen vs eclipse seam web project or vice versa.

Why would I use one over the other?

Thanks,
czetsuya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command line seam-gen stuffs the whole application into a single project and included some files that we didn't need (6 versions of the messages file, for example, each in a differnet language).

The eclipse jboss tools seam-gen produces a bit more modular, streamlined app.  It generates 3 separate projects (4 if you want a test project).  It took some time to get used to it, but once I got it down, I prefer it.  Additionally, when you create he project in eclipse you can leverage more easily the benefits of using those integrated tools.

You can do this with a seam-gen commandline-generated project as well by creating an eclipse project using your seam-gen project as source , but it takes some fiddling around in eclipse to get the settings just right.

My recommendation is to go with eclipse/jboss tools.  If you come from a command-line centric background (as I did), the learnign curve may be a bit steeper, but in the end it will be worth it.  Use the jboss tools forum for questions you have about this project.

Good luck. Once you get going with eclipse/jboss you'll find it's a great environment to work in.

Comment: I see thanks for your comment. What I want from seam-gen is the build.xml file that is automatically created :-D. Well I guess I can just copy that one.